# How data can be stored in the front end in javascript and rendered to the UI using templates like angular?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I have written javascript function to call my controller method.But the initial values I would want javascript to load and render to UI using angular templates? How is this possible as I dont want any issue for the controller method called from javascript.

```
function propertyChange(ev) {            
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //New browsers.
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var formData = new FormData(document.forms.Property);
    }
    if (request != null) {
        var url = "Calculator/NetWorth";
        request.open("POST", url, false);
        request.send(formData)
        
    }

    totalAssets.value = request.response;
}
```

html code below

```
<form name="Property"  >
  <p>
      <br/><br />
  </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Property</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Property1  </td>
            <td> 
                <input type="number" onchange="propertyChange(event)"
                       id="property1" name="property1" min="0"
                       value="1500.00" ng-model="property1"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Property2  </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="property2" name="property2"
                       min="0" value="4100.00" ng-model="property2"
                       onchange="propertyChange(event)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Total Expenditure </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="totalExpenditure"
                        name="totalExpenditure" contenteditable="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, one uses the [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage) to make POST requests to the server. This is covered in the [AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: I am new to Angular, looked into multiple tutorials but couldnt find right one. Could you share me the approach for this issue please?

Comment: Anyone who can update on this please?

Comment: Can someone help me on how to convert the above code in angular template

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood well, but if what you want is to store the form values locally in the browser so you dont have to make any api call when loading the page, you can use [localStorage API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). But I wouldnt recommend you to do this because if any other client makes changes to the backend data you will not load correct values when loading the page, I would recommend to make an api call to load initial values instead, but here I have an alternative for you.

For this kind of small pieces of logic I would recommend to use [KnockoutJs](https://knockoutjs.com/), it is very quick to learn and adapt

JavaScript:

```
var PropertyViewModel = function() {
    function getLocalValue(fieldName, defaultValue = null) {
        let value = localStorage.getItem(fieldName);
      
        if (!value && defaultValue) {
          value = defaultValue;
        }
      
        return value;
    }
    
    this.setLocalValue = function (fieldName, fieldValue) {
        fieldName && fieldValue && localStorage.setItem(fieldName, fieldValue);
    }
    
    this.property1 = ko.observable(getLocalValue('property1', 10));
    this.property2 = ko.observable(getLocalValue('property2', 20));

    this.propertyChange = function(ev) {
        var request;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            //New browsers.
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var formData = new FormData(document.forms.Property);
        }

        if (request != null) {
            var url = "Calculator/NetWorth";
            request.open("POST", url, false);
            request.send(formData)
        }

        totalAssets.value = request.response;
        this.setLocalValue('property1', this.property1());
        this.setLocalValue('property2', this.property2());
    }
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new PropertyViewModel());
```

Html Template:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min.js"></script>

<form name="Property"  >
  <p>
      <br/><br />
  </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Property</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Property1  </td>
            <td> 
                <input type="number"
                       id="property1"
                       name="property1"
                       min="0"
                       data-bind="value: property1, event: { change: propertyChange }"                 />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Property2  </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number"
                       id="property2"
                       name="property2"
                       min="0"
                       data-bind="value: property2, event: { change: propertyChange }"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Total Expenditure </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="totalExpenditure"
                        name="totalExpenditure" contenteditable="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```